# 'Undo-ing' changes to Gem source

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I was debugging a gem a while ago and accidentally left in some code that causes my project to hang when it makes use of that gem. How can I restore the clean source? Is the only option to uninstall and reinstall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

```
gem pristine foo
```

Does this for the gem of that name. You can also pass `--all` to rebuild all gems. This works by comparing what's in the .gem file (which is a tar archive in disguise) with the actual files. More details in the [documentation](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-pristine)

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall that gem with `gem uninstall <gem_name>` and then reinstall via `gem install <gem_name>` or `bundle install`.